# Subject inside setTimeout() is not working

Tags: javascript, observable, settimeout, subject

I am trying to work on Subject from RxJS. In below 2 code snippets the output is different. I couldn't understand why 'subscribe' inside 'setTimeout' method is not logging the value. Could anyone please help me through it? Thank you.

```
import { Subject, from, Observable } from 'rxjs';

const subject = new Subject();

subject.subscribe((value) => console.log(value)); 

setTimeout(() => {
  subject.subscribe((value) => console.log(value)); 
}, 2000);

const observable = new Observable((observer) => {
  console.log('called only once')
  observer.next(Math.random())
});  

observable.subscribe(subject); 

Output: 

called only once
0.253655945545456
```

=================================================

```
import { Subject, from, Observable } from 'rxjs';

const subject = new Subject();

subject.subscribe((value) => console.log(value)); 
subject.subscribe((value) => console.log(value)); 

const observable = new Observable((observer) => {
  console.log('called only once')
  observer.next(Math.random())
});  

observable.subscribe(subject); 

Output: 

called only once
0.253655945545456
0.253655945545456
```

Comment: The code inside the `setTimeout()` hasn't been executed when you call `.next()`, so there is only one subscriber at that time.  2 seconds later there are 2.  What are you actually trying to do with the timeout?

Comment: @Archer Thank you.

if it is like that, why the value is not logged into console after 2 seconds?

Comment: When you call `observer.next()` it executes the subscriber methods.  At that time there is only 1 subscriber.  Subscribers don't run retroactively, so if it isn't subscribed when an event occurs then it doesn't know about it.  Call `observer.next()` again after 3 seconds and you'll see 2 ouputs that time.

Comment: @Archer Thank you very much. I got it now.